# Google Analytics data does not show during the middle of the day

Tags: google-analytics

I have a weird problem with one of google analytics accounts and I'm hoping someone can help me figure what might be causing it.

Essentially, in the middle of the day, Google Analytics stops showing data. It will show me my hourly revenue till about noon and then the data regresses back to show only hourly revenue till 8 in the morning. This screenshot was taken at 1:30 PM today:

[image]

The hourly revenue will update again at around 4 PM. Its a very irritating problem and I can't find any solutions on google for it.

Let me know if I need to provide any additional information that might help you understand my situation.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is this something new? Because I'm having issues with revenue tracking over the last 24 hours.

Comment: I've been facing this issue for the last month or so. What are you doing to try and fix it?